# why do I get NA values when resampling rasters in r

Tags: r, raster

I have two rasters with different extents but when i use resample in R the output is a blank raster......How can I solve the problem?
see below some of the codes used....the resampled raster apperars with NA in the values....

```
show(alt)

class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 1800, 4320, 7776000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.08333334, 0.08333334  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -60, 90.00001  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs 
data source : C:\Users\Mafalda\Documents\bio_5m_esri\alt5.asc 
names       : alt5 
values      : -2147483648, 2147483647  (min, max)

show(hfp)

class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 16382, 36081, 591078942  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
extent      : -18040094, 18040906, -7363043, 9018957  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs 
data source : C:\Users\Mafalda\Desktop\Iva\HumanFootprintv2\hfp2009.asc 
names       : hfp2009 
values      : -2147483648, 2147483647  (min, max)

hfpResamp <- resample(hfp, alt, resample='bilinear')

show(hfpResamp)

class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 1800, 4320, 7776000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.08333334, 0.08333334  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -60, 90.00001  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs 
data source : in memory
names       : hfp2009 
values      : NA, NA  (min, max)

extent(hfp)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : -18040094 
xmax        : 18040906 
ymin        : -7363043 
ymax        : 9018957 


extent(alt)

class       : Extent 
xmin        : -180 
xmax        : 180 
ymin        : -60 
ymax        : 90.00001
```

Comment: looks like your raster `hfp` is projected

Answer (score 1):

You need to `reproject` your `hfp` file first:

```
hfp_re <- projectRaster(hfp, alt)
# now you can resample:
hfpResamp <- resample(hfp_re, alt, resample='bilinear')
```

Comment: You have to define the projection for your htf raster first. The current reference is not correct.

Comment: This is returning `input projection is NA`?